# Stretching the ul-li menu with padding to fit the full width

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu of floated ul/li's (the ), that is with changing width, but I would like to fill the complete width of the containing div.

the code:

```
#main-content ul.jwts_tabbernav {  
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    text-align: center; 
}

#main-content ul.jwts_tabbernav li a,
#main-content ul.jwts_tabbernav li a:link, 
#main-content ul.jwts_tabbernav li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #734C2F; outline: 1px solid #734C2F;
    color: #734C2F;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 35px;
}
```

the development pages (with two different menu widths):

http://www.kaplareva.com/polarinvest/?p=224

http://www.kaplareva.com/polarinvest/?p=227

Any idea how this could be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following changes will make the list-items expand to fill the container.

```
ul {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

li {
    display:table-cell;
}

a {
    display:block
}
```

The one caveat is that [display:table-cell](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell) and [display:table](http://caniuse.com/#search=table) are not supported natively in IE6/7 so if you need to support those browsers then you will need another solution. With [IE6 usage](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) down to just 7.1% and [IE7 usage](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201104-201204) at 2.54%, I know fewer and fewer designers are supporting them.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, it works. I don't mind so much about the IEs, good that they are more and more out of usage. And if the client complains, I'll make a patch for it through the ifIE6 or ifIE7 stylesheets...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, you simply need to make the `a` elements within the `li` elements `display: block`:

```
#main-content ul.jwts_tabbernav li a,
#main-content ul.jwts_tabbernav li a:link, 
#main-content ul.jwts_tabbernav li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #734C2F; outline: 1px solid #734C2F;
    color: #734C2F;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 35px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a display block

```
#menu a {
    display: block;
}
```